# How to query on AWS Athena partitioned table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, partition

**Summary of the Question**

> When I attempts to `SELECT` query the partitioned table with `WHERE` clause, Athena produce an error.

There are 4 types of partitions, in my `log` table.

- year `string`
- month `string`
- day `string`
- hour `string`

I tried `SELECT` query on partitioned table.
But got the below error message.

**ERROR Message**

```
GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: No value present
This query ran against the "default" database, unless qualified by the query.
```

**SELECT Query that I Tried**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE year='2020'
  AND month='10'
  AND day ='05';
```

AND

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "default"."logs"
WHERE year='2020'
  AND month='10'
  AND day ='05';
```

Since error message about `No value present`, I checked the partitions results.

```sql
SHOW PARTITIONS logs;
```

**Results**

```
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=17
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=11
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=19
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=04
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=18
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=15
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=14
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=16
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=13
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=21
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=05
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=08
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=20
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=12
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=03
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=01
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=10
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=02
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=09
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=22
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=23
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=06
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=07
year=2020/month=10/day=05/hour=00
year=2020/month=10/day=04/hour=00
```

I would greatly appreciate your help.

---

### Further Info

`CREATE TABLE` command that I used

**Create Table**

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `logs`(
  `date` date, 
  `time` string, 
  `location` string, 
  `bytes` bigint, 
  `request_ip` string, 
  `method` string, 
  `host` string, 
  `uri` string, 
  `status` int, 
  `referrer` string, 
  `user_agent` string, 
  `query_string` string, 
  `cookie` string, 
  `result_type` string, 
  `request_id` string, 
  `host_header` string, 
  `request_protocol` string, 
  `request_bytes` bigint, 
  `time_taken` float, 
  `xforwarded_for` string, 
  `ssl_protocol` string, 
  `ssl_cipher` string, 
  `response_result_type` string, 
  `http_version` string, 
  `fle_status` string, 
  `fle_encrypted_fields` int)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` string, 
  `month` string, 
  `day` string, 
  `hour` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='^(?!#)([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)\\\\s+([^ \\\\t]+)$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mybucket/path'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.date.format'='yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.date.interval'='1', 
  'projection.date.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
  'projection.date.range'='2019/11/27, NOW-1DAYS', 
  'projection.date.type'='date', 
  'projection.day.type'='string', 
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.hour.type'='string', 
  'projection.month.type'='string', 
  'projection.year.type'='string', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='2', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://mybucket/path/distributionID/${year}/${month}/${day}/${hour}/', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1575005094')
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the data, and the `CREATE TABLE` command that was used to create the table, so that we can try to reproduce the situation?

Comment: Sure, @JohnRotenstein.
As per your request, I've added `CREATE TABLE` Info.
Please check the above question.

Comment: Ah! It looks like you are querying logs from Amazon CloudFront. This might help: [Querying Amazon CloudFront Logs - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html). Have you somehow placed the logs into sub-directories based on the date(s) in the files?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
Ok, I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: what did you got when you just ran select * from logs?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy, 
It returns a same error.  

```
GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: No value present
This query ran against the "default" database, unless qualified by the query. 
```

Comment: I think it raised the issue after I partitioned `logs` table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your table uses partition projection, but your configuration does not match the partitioning correctly. Partition projection is a fairly new feature, and the documentation still leaves a bit to be desired so I completely understand that it's confusing. I think I see what you're trying to do.

The partition projection configuration must exactly match the partition keys of the table. In your case there are four partition keys of the table, and the partition projection configuration mentions five. In addition to that the types of four are wrong, there is no `string` partition projection type.

You can fix the problem by making two changes. First change the partition keys like this:

```sql
PARTITIONED BY (
  `date` string,
  `hour` string
)
```

This removes the "year", "month", and "day" partition keys in favour of a "date" key. Having separate date components just because they are separate "directories" is not necessary, and just having a "date" key will make queries much easier to write.

Then you change the table properties to this:

```sql
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.date.format' = 'yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.date.interval' = '1', 
  'projection.date.interval.unit' = 'DAYS', 
  'projection.date.range' = '2019/11/27, NOW-1DAYS', 
  'projection.date.type' = 'date', 
  'projection.hour.type' = 'integer',
  'projection.hour.range' = '0-23',
  'projection.hour.digits' = '2',
  'projection.enabled' = 'true',
  'storage.location.template'='s3://mybucket/path/distributionID/${date}/${hour}/', 
  'skip.header.line.count' = '2'
)
```

This tells Athena that the "date" partition key is of type `date`, and that it's formatted as "YYYY/MM/DD" (which corresponds to the format in the S3 URIs, this is important). It also tells Athena that the "hour" partition key is an `integer` with range 0-23, formatted with two digits (i.e. zero-filled). Finally it specifies how these partition keys map to the locations of partitions on S3. When the date in a query is "2020/10/06" that string will be inserted verbatim in the location template.

With those changes you should be able to run queries like the following ("date" is a reserved word and must be quoted when it's the name of a column):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE "date" = '2020/10/06'
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2020/10/01' AND '2020/10/06'
AND hour BETWEEN 9 AND 21
```

Note that the date format must be exactly like the format in the partition projection configuration, i.e. `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Comment: @MOONBLUE if this helped please upvote and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, Theo.
It's very helpful for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Theo's answer helped specially with the number of digits for hour and day, since my S3 is partitioned in the format YYYY/MM/DD:

```
  'projection.hour.digits' = '2'
```

This was the key to make it work here. Thanks @theo

In my case, what I use is the following, for parquet files:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_name`(
  `id` string, 
   -- more columns..
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` string, 
  `month` string, 
  `day` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://fullbucketname/full_prefix_dir'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'projection.day.range'='1,31', 
  'projection.day.type'='integer', 
  'projection.day.digits' = '2',
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.month.range'='1,12', 
  'projection.month.type'='integer',
  'projection.month.digits' = '2',
  'projection.year.range'='2020,2051',
  'projection.year.type'='integer',
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucketname/prefixdir/year=${year}/month=${month}/day=${day}', 
  'typeOfData'='file'
)
```

Comment: It helped me too, thanks!